# How can I make same result for re.findall and re.finditer on regular expressions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

## Topic

I would like to extract words or quotes with quotations without quotations using `re.finditer()` function rather than re.findall().

```
text = 'This is a very "sweet" and "beautiful" cake.'

-> ['sweet', 'beautiful']
```

## output an issue

The `re.finditer()` function returns with quotations and I have no idea how to get rid of the top and bottom double quotations.

```
['sweet', 'beautiful']
['"sweet"', '"beautiful"']
```

## Code

```py
import re
text = 'This is a very "sweet" and "beautiful" cake.'
all = re.findall('"(.*?)"', text)
print(all)

all_obj = re.finditer('"(.*?)"', text)
result = []
for obj in all_obj:
    result.append(obj.group())
print(result)
```

## What I have tried to do

Without stripping, is there any solution to fix this issue?

```
final_result = []
for word in result:
    final_result.append(word.rstrip('"').lstrip('"'))
print(final_result)

['sweet', 'beautiful']
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `.group(1)` to match and extract your group:

```
result.append(obj.group(1))
```